# Utility to generate DataLayer

Tags: c#-4.0, utility, data-layers

I need to write a Utility, which will capable to generate Data Layer from any following Databases :
  Mssql
  MySQL
  Oracle

For example :
I have SQL Database which contains several Tables, Views, Procs, Functions etc. With the use of above utility, I would be able to generate all Datalayer containing Entity classes and their mappings or something like that so, on this basis I would be able to write my Business Layer and then UI.

I do not want to use any utilities for this purpose.

Any help in this regard will be much appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use one that's already been written?  ADO.Net will reverse engineer a database for you.  Apparently, there's an Entity Data Model Wizard that does this.  What's wrong with that?

Comment: @S.lott - You are absolutely right, the utilities are avilable but as i mentioned, I do not want to use utilities. Need to write own.

Comment: Why?  Please explain why.  What's wrong with the existing utilities?

Comment: @S.Lott - In  plain words, Organization do not wnat to use. Hope, you will provide some specific solution rather than asking questions.

Comment: It's very, very hard to do.  It's quite complex to reason correctly about all the odd and unusual things that are seen in relational databases.  Indeed, the problem is so hard that all of the "reverse engineer a model from a database" tools are very complex, very expensive, and do a poor job of reverse engineering.  If you want a solution that works, use the wizard you already have in in your Visual Studio.  If you want to write your own, then get to work designing something.  We won't design it for you.  Especially for free. It's very, very complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the Entity Data Model Wizard.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738677.aspx

Comment: Hey DKnaak - I have already discussed the same thing with S.Lott, just take a look. I need to create it at my end. I found some utility which are open-sources, if you have any info for the same let me know?